# Limit Max Number of Requests Per Hour with `didip/tollbooth`

Tags: go, bucket, rate-limiting

I'm new to rate limiting and want to use [tollbooth](https://github.com/didip/tollbooth) to limit HTTP requests.

I also read the [Token Bucket Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) page on Wikipedia.

For a simple test app, I want to limit the max number of concurrent requests to `10` regardless of request IP, and have a max burst size of `3` based on request IP.

NOTE: The `10` and `3` are just to make rate limiting easier to observe.

Below is my code based on the examples on `tollbooth`'s [GitHub page](https://github.com/didip/tollbooth):

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/didip/tollbooth/v7"
    "github.com/didip/tollbooth/v7/limiter"
)

func main() {
    lmt := tollbooth.NewLimiter(3, &limiter.ExpirableOptions{DefaultExpirationTTL: time.Hour})

    http.Handle("/", tollbooth.LimitFuncHandler(lmt, HelloHandler))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func HelloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
}
```

I test the code by running `curl -i localhost:8080` several times in rapid succession, and I do get `HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests` errors whenever I exceed the rate limit I set.

Below are my questions:

1. How do I use `tollbooth` to limit max number of concurrent requests to something like `10`? And does it even make sense to do so? I assume it does because rate limiting based only on IPs sounds like the server could still go out of memory when too many IPs access it at once.
2. Am I approaching rate limiting correctly, or am I missing something? Perhaps this is something that's better handled by whatever load balancer is working with the app in the cloud?

***UPDATE:*** Here's my working code based on [Woody1193](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121975/woody1193)'s answer:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/didip/tollbooth/v7"
    "github.com/didip/tollbooth/v7/limiter"
)

func main() {
    ipLimiter := tollbooth.NewLimiter(3, &limiter.ExpirableOptions{DefaultExpirationTTL: time.Hour})
    globalLimiter := NewConcurrentLimiter(10)

    http.Handle("/", globalLimiter.LimitConcurrentRequests(ipLimiter, HelloHandler))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func HelloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
}

type ConcurrentLimiter struct {
    max     int
    current int
    mut     sync.Mutex
}

func NewConcurrentLimiter(limit int) *ConcurrentLimiter {
    return &ConcurrentLimiter{
        max: limit,
    }
}

func (limiter *ConcurrentLimiter) LimitConcurrentRequests(lmt *limiter.Limiter,
    handler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) http.Handler {

    middle := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        limiter.mut.Lock()
        maxHit := limiter.current == limiter.max

        if maxHit {
            limiter.mut.Unlock()
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(429), http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }

        limiter.current += 1
        limiter.mut.Unlock()

        defer func() {
            limiter.mut.Lock()
            limiter.current -= 1
            limiter.mut.Unlock()
        }()

        // There's no rate-limit error, serve the next handler.
        handler(w, r)
    }

    return tollbooth.LimitHandler(lmt, http.HandlerFunc(middle))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that tollbooth doesn't offer the functionality you're looking for. However, you can roll your own:

```
type ConcurrentLimiter struct {
    max int
    current int
    mut sync.Mutex
}

func NewConcurrentLimiter(limit int) *ConcurrentLimiter {
    return &ConcurrentLimiter {
        max: limit,
        mut: new(sync.Mutex),
    }
}

func (limiter *ConcurrentLimiter) LimitConcurrentRequests(lmt *limiter.Limiter, 
    next http.Handler) http.Handler {

    middle := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        limiter.mut.Lock()
        maxHit := limiter.current == limiter.max
        if maxHit {
            limiter.mut.Unlock()
            httpError := // Insert your HTTP error here
            return
        }

        limiter.current += 1
        limiter.mut.Unlock()

        defer func() {
            limiter.mut.Lock()
            limiter.current -= 1
            limiter.mut.Unlock()
        }()

        // There's no rate-limit error, serve the next handler.
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }

    return tollbooth.LimitHandler(lmt, http.HandlerFunc(middle))
}
```

Then, in your setup you can do:

```
http.Handle("/", NewConcurrentLimiter(10).LimitConcurrentRequests(HelloHandler))
```

This code works by maintaining a value describing how many requests the API is currently handling and returning an error if the maximum value has been met. The `Mutex` is used to ensure that the value is updated regardless of concurrent requests.

I had to inject the `tollbooth.Limiter` into the limiter I wrote because of the way tollbooth handles such functions (i.e. it doesn't operate as a middleware).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, `tollbooth` expects a `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)` but `LimitConcurrentRequests` doesn't return anything. I tried tweaking the code, but I got an `all goroutines are asleep` error. Here's my edited code so far: https://go.dev/play/p/sz3VvpgjyJL

Comment: I found the problem about the goroutines being asleep (deadlock) issue. I just had to take out the lines that incremented the mutex and unlocked it. However, I can't seem to get the expected "Too Many Requests" error after calling the slow endpoint (that sleeps for 10 seconds) more than 3 times. Here's my code so far: https://go.dev/play/p/3AZaP5Wyzko

Comment: @FloatingSunfish Let me update my answer.

Comment: It finally worked! I had to edit the code a bit so it can accept Handler functions directly instead of `http.Handler`, but everything works as expected now! Here's the updated code: https://go.dev/play/p/0rlTgBqgV4q

Comment: Just accepted your answer. Please ignore the Edit I accidentally made. Meant to update my Question and didn't realize I could edit Answers now too. Many thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @FloatingSunfish No problem at all. Glad I could be of service.